# Visual Studio test, Process.Start, SQLCMD and Windows Command Processor error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mstest, .net-4.5, sqlcmd

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 and I'm developing some integration tests using Visual Studio's test framework (*mstest*).

Some days ago I found some info regarding that now Visual Studio 2012 can execute tests in the output directory (i.e. *bin\Debug*, *bin\Release*) and I disabled *deployment* in order to simplify a lot of things.

Although most of the things worked as expected, I found a big problem: some `[ClassInitialize]` code executes a process using `Process` class and, just after disabling *deployment*, whenever a process is launched, I get this error:

[image]

My first impression was that maybe something in the process launching was incorrect and I copy-pasted the same command and arguments into a **CMD** and it worked as expected.

After some investigation, I figured out why happened this: because I configured test runner to be launched as a 64bit process. After switching to X86, for example `Process.Start("cmd")` worked.

But what's worse is **SQLCMD** - the actual process that I'm launching within test run - still fails with the so-called error.

This error happens when any process is launched within Visual Studio test runner.

**What happens with SQLCMD when launched from a test runner?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trials and errors finally I've solved the problem.

- Now I can run tests as a 64bit process (I thought this was the main problem but I was mistaken!).
- I can still run tests from the output directory!

But what I had to change to get it work properly? The `.runsettings` file. **It was just commenting out `<DataCollectionRunSettings>` XML element... And suddenly *SQLCMD* process started to work again!**

I really don't know why commenting out that configuration element did the trick, but the point is that, as I only want integration tests and run them "as is", this solution is fine for me.

Anyway, if anyone can explain why commenting out `<DataCollectionRunSettings>` elements makes this effect, it'll be appreciated.

Thank you anyway!